# Migrating Live/production WordPress site to Laragon

Tags: wordpress, web-deployment, laragon

I'm trying to set up my Live WordPress site into a local environment, Laragon. I have tried using a plugin call WPvivid, but it does not seem to be working correctly. So, that leaves me with 1) use another plugin or 2) manually move the site over, I would like to learn the latter. I understand how to move the Database over and edit the config file to connect to the server. The problem is when I move the WP-content file over to the local WordPress site noting is happening, I have no content available to me.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is

1. Quick create -> wordpress
2. access the local url you made
3. select the language (wordpress set up)
4. before setting up the id and password of wordpress (do not save the info), find your new local wordpress folder.
5. copy and paste the original "wp-content" file you had (the file of live wordpress site) to change the local wp-content file.
6. copy and paste the original "sql" file you had (the file of live wordpress site) to change the local wp-content file. To do that, access to yoururl/phpmyadmin, and change import the sql file you had.
7. after that, finish the 3rd process.

It would be easy if you find a great video of explaining this procedure.